# Updating repeated data in different column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with geographical data about tracks, basically there are many points with lat/long coordinates that make up a track. Now, my problem is that some tracks "share" points and I'd like to reference these shared points in another field in the same table. Let me exemplify:

```
TrackName | PointNo | Lat | Long | SharedTrack | SharedPoint
------------------------------------------------------------
Track1    | 1       |-35.3| 100.4| null        | null
Track1    | 2       |-35.2| 100.5| null        | null
Track1    | 3       |-35.1| 100.6| null        | null
Track2    | 1       |-34.9| 100.8| null        | null
Track2    | 2       |-35.0| 100.7| null        | null
Track2    | 3       |-35.1| 100.6| null        | null
```

Some records may have the same *Lat* and *Long* values, this is what we call a *SharedPoint*. So now, I have to update all records so that the *SharedPoints* take the *Lat* and *Long* values from the Track with the lowest *TrackName*... Following the same example, this would be:

```
TrackName | PointNo | Lat | Long | SharedTrack | SharedPoint
------------------------------------------------------------
Track1    | 1       |-35.3| 100.4| null        | null
Track1    | 2       |-35.2| 100.5| null        | null
Track1    | 3       |-35.1| 100.6| null        | null
Track2    | 1       |-34.9| 100.8| null        | null
Track2    | 2       |-35.0| 100.7| null        | null
Track2    | 3       |-35.1| 100.6| Track1      | 3
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to provide the table schema and insert statements. It will help others to help you to get your answer faster.

Comment: Why do you only want to update Track2 with Track1 info when Track1 is also shared with Track2 - shouldn't you update both rows?

Comment: @LouieBao Actually it would be better to post that information here, so that responders can work/test wherever they want, without being forced to go to an arbitrary secondary site.

Comment: @AaronBertrand What the client said is that the tracks with the lowest name are older so the newer ones are "on top" of the older ones... The DB isn't actually about tracks but it was the simplest way of describing it I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table Track
(
    TrackName varchar(max)
    , PointNo int
    , Lat  decimal(9, 1)
    , Long decimal(9, 1)
    , SharedTrack   varchar(max) 
    , SharedPoint int
)

insert Track 
values ('Track1' , 1 , -35.3, 100.4, null , null)
, ('Track1' , 2 , -35.2, 100.5, null , null)
, ('Track1' , 3 , -35.1, 100.6, null , null)
, ('Track2' , 1 , -34.9, 100.8, null , null)
, ('Track2' , 2 , -35.0, 100.7, null , null)
, ('Track2' , 3 , -35.1, 100.6, null , null)
, ('Track3' , 3 , -35.1, 100.6, null , null)
, ('Track4' , 1 , -35.1, 100.6, null , null)

;with cte
as
(
    -- Find all the shared tracks first.
    select a.Lat, b.Long, a.TrackName, b.TrackName as 'LowTrackName'
    from Track a
    join Track b    on a.Lat = b.Lat and a.Long = b.Long 
                        and a.TrackName > b.TrackName
)
, cte_2
as
(
    -- Get the lowest TrackName 
    select Lat, Long, TrackName, min(LowTrackName) as 'MinTrackName'
    from cte
    group by Lat, Long, TrackName
)
, cte_3
as
(
    -- Get the matching PointNo for the lowest TrackName
    select a.Lat, a.Long, a.TrackName, a.MinTrackName, b.PointNo
    from cte_2 a
    join Track b    on a.Lat = b.Lat
                        and a.Long = b.Long
                        and a.MinTrackName = b.TrackName
)
update a
set SharedTrack = b.MinTrackName
    , SharedPoint = b.PointNo
from Track a
join cte_3 b        on  a.Lat = b.Lat
                        and a.Long = b.Long
                        and a.TrackName = b.TrackName
where SharedTrack is null
and SharedPoint is null
```